# Spring MVC - The request sent by the client was syntatically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> print(@RequestBody final RequestModel request) throw ApiException {
    return null;
}
```

And in my RequestModel:

```
class RequestModel {
    private String name;
    private CustomData data;
}
```

CustomData:

```
class CustomData {
    private String data;
}
```

When I make POST request without the "data" field, it works. But if I add the "data" field, I'm getting a 400, The request sent by the client was syntatically incorrect.

Comment: What's `private data`? Is it a class? Do you mean `private String data;`?

Comment: My bad, yes it's a String

Comment: Até sending a json? Show the json body.

Comment: {name: "test", data: { data: "test" }}}

Comment: Put double quotes in the Fields names and remove the last brackets

Comment: Tried it but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

O dont know If you wrote all the code, but tou should implements serializable and write setters and getters.

But, answering your question, you should annotate your fields with @JsonProperty to specify the required flag.

Comment: I've already implemented serializable and have getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted JSON should be something like this :

```
{
   "name":"Luke",
   "data": {
         "data":"I am your father"
    }
}
```

OBS: if you are using Postman, please set the header : key: Content-Type, value: application/json

You should specify an endpoint:
Example :

```
@PostMapping("/data")
```

Instead of

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST })
```

If you are using default port, try again the post to :

```
http://localhost:8080/data
```

OBS: RequestModel and CustomerData must have getters and setters.